# iPhone-Simulator: Screenshots & copyrights

Tags: iphone, simulator

Has apple protected the iPhone-Simulator-UI?

I want to publish some screenshots of my app.

Comment: I suppose you mean the image of the hardware around the virtual screen, not the GUI artwork on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does have some specific rules about using the actual image of the iPhone (or iPad). 
If you want to use the image of the phone itself, or you want to use the "Available on the App Store" badge, you should agree to the App Marketing License Agreement (found in the "Marketing Resources" section of the iOS developer center), and read the App Marketing and Identity Guidelines for Developers (also in the Marketing Resources section).

Apple also provides some official artwork (as Photoshop files) for the iPhone4 and iPad for developers to use in print and on the web.

See https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/#storelogo for all of these.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen people publish screenshots from the simulator all the time, have not heard of any issues.

However, there are some really nice Photoshop files floating around that have shadows, relflection, and gloss that really make the screenshots look nice. Google for "iphone device photoshop template"

Answer (score 0):

Publishing screenshots of your app is perfectly OK.

Comment: As long as the device itself is not included in the screenshot. I've been rejected for using an iMac in the logo and splash screen of my app, so I reckon that's all copyrighted material.